# glDrawElements not drawing anything to screen

Tags: c++, opengl

Whenever I try to draw a mesh using glDrawElements, my program gets no errors, but it doesn't draw anything. I'm pretty sure that the issue is with glDrawElements since if I comment glDrawElements out and replace it with glDrawArrays, it works perfectly. So, my question is, can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

Also glGetError returns no errors

```
#include "Mesh.h"

Mesh::Mesh(glm::vec2* vertices, glm::vec2* texCoords, GLushort* elements, int size)
{
    m_size = size;
    m_vertices = vertices;
    m_elements = elements;
    movementVector = glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size * sizeof(float), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glGenBuffers(1, &tex_vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tex_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size * sizeof(float), texCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // note: I assume that vertex positions are location 0 
    int dimensions = 2; // 2d data for texture coords 
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, dimensions, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (1); // don't forget this!

    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

}


Mesh::~Mesh()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vbo);
}

void Mesh::Draw()
{
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 8);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Here's a link to the code handling drawing objects to the screen, also, I have tested my shaders, they are fully functional and unless drawing via glDrawElements requires changes to the shaders as well, then there is nothing that is causing this with them.

Comment: Could it be perhaps that your call to
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW); should rather write sizeof(GLushort)*number_of_elements ?

Comment: OMG... you sir deserve a cookie, a potato, and a shiny nickel. Thank you so much, I've been trying to fix that error for soooo long and I can't believe that it was so simple, thank you so much. I never even considered that it was just running out of memory to store the Element buffer!

Comment: Glad to have helped. :)